# Memory management, UIScrollView containing 24 UIButtons and UILabels per page. How can I make this more efficient?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview

I am building an app that uses buttons to represent every user. Kind of like chat heads. These are arranged in rows in a `UIScrollView`. 4 `buttons` per row and below the button a UILabel  displaying the username. These `buttons` are all stored in a NSMutable array along with their images. Each image is about 50kb in size. After about 100 `UIButtons` it starts to get a little lag scrolling (running on an iPhone 5). The code to init the buttons is below, images are fetched from Parse.com:

```
-(void)initButtonsFromFriendsArray: (NSMutableArray *)friends {


    for(int i=0; i<[self.currentUser.friends count]; i++) {

        //need someway to reference the buttons
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 70)];
        //tag is the same as the element in the array
        button.tag=i;
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(friendTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        [self.buttons addObject:button];
        PFUser *user = friends[i];
        PFFile *userImageFile = user[@"profilePic"];
        [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            }
        }];

    }

    //after init want to display

    [self refreshButtons];

}
```

The method `refreshButtons` just iterates though that array placing them in the content `UIView` (contained in the UIScrollView), arranging them in rows of 4. Is there anyway I can be efficient in the memory management? Would the array be taking up a lot of memory space with the images stored inside or is it all the `UIViews` on the screen? Not really sure how to go about optimising it. I can't keep reloading images from the server as that is slow so they need to be stored in that array. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: 1. Don't use the scrollview, use the UITableView with lazy loading. 2. Don't add the UIControls like buttons, images in the array. Use the reuse identifier in the tableviewcell and create them dynamically.

Comment: To handle memory management stay out of UIScrollView for this requirement, use tableview as cell will get created dynamically for visible cells only. For image display use  lazy loading : Demo -https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html.

Comment: `UICollectionView` is another option for this kind of purposes.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance but what is lazy loading?

Comment: @Kex Check this demo for lazy loading : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html